# C# - Windows Form como pesquisar em um Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, lista, algoritmo-de-busca, datagridview

Tenho um `datagridview` que é preenchido a partir de uma lista com dados. Ao iniciar a tela eu faço um `SELECT` buscando todos os registros do banco. Como faço para realizar uma pesquisa nesta lista e apresentar no `datagridview`?

Minha datagridView é preenchida assim:

```
        gridBackups2.DataSource = listaAux;
        for (int i = 0; i < listaAux.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= gridBackups2.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    gridBackups2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = listaBackupAtivos[i].id + "";
                }
                if (j == 1)
                {
                    gridBackups2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = listaBackupAtivos[i].customer + "";
                }
                if (j == 2)
                {
                    gridBackups2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = getCliente(listaBackupAtivos[i].customer);
                }
                if (j == 3)
                {
                    gridBackups2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = listaBackupAtivos[i].scheduleTime;
                }
                if (j == 4)
                {
                    gridBackups2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = retornaStatus(listaBackupAtivos[i].status);
                }
            }
        }
```

A `grid` esta sendo preenchida corretamente (ID, nome, Data). Como eu faço para **realizar uma pesquisa**, por exemplo pelo nome que esta preenchido na grid, **sem que eu precise realizar outro select**? Pois se toda vez que eu for pesquisar eu precisar fazer um select, ficará muito lento. Há alguma forma de eu pesquisar diretamente na lista que eu carrego quando inicio o programa?

---

**EDIT:**

```
private void txPesquisar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    dt = (DataTable) gridBackups2.DataSource; 

    System.Console.WriteLine("Teste dt> " + dt.Columns.Count); 
    System.Console.WriteLine("Teste grid> " + gridBackups2.Columns.Count); 

    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Cliente like '%{txPesquisar.Text}%'"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais simples de filtrar uma `DataGridView` é utilizando um `DataTable`, que permite de raíz filtrar, ordenar colunas, etc.

Como, aparentemente, está a utilizar uma `List`, então é necessário implementar um método de conversão para `DataTable`:

```
private DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }

    object[] values = new object[props.Count];

    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);

        table.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Para atribuir o DataSource:

```
DataTable dt = ToDataTable(listAux);
gridBackups2.DataSource = dt;
```

Para filtrar os resultados:

```
(gridBackups2.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = $"coluna like '%{txtFiltro.Text}%'";
```

Onde a `coluna` representa o nome da coluna que pretende filtrar e o controlo `txtFiltro` a `TextBox` onde está a definir o filtro.

Com um `DataTable` definido como `DataSource` consegue filtrar os resultados em tempo real sem ser necessário código adicional.

Comment: Bom dia João, fiz as alterações mas não obtive sucesso. Quando vou fazer a pesquisa da erro: **Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento do tipo "System.Data.EvaluateException" em System.Data.dll
Não é possível encontrar a coluna [Cliente].**
Realizei um teste:
**System.Console.WriteLine("Teste dt> " + dt.Columns.Count);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Teste grid> " + gridBackups2.Columns.Count);**
E o resultado foi:

Teste dt> 0
Teste grid> 5 

Ou seja, o DataTable não esta pegando as informações e por isso não localiza a coluna **Cliente**. Sabe me dizer o que esta errado?

Comment: **Este é o evento no campo TextBox**

private void txPesquisar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = (DataTable) gridBackups2.DataSource;


            System.Console.WriteLine("Teste dt> " + dt.Columns.Count);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Teste grid> " + gridBackups2.Columns.Count);

            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Cliente like '%{txPesquisar.Text}%'";
        }

Comment: E a coluna `Cliente` existe no seu `DataTable`?

Comment: O nome da coluna existe no gridBackups2, porém o Datatable vem com zero colunas

Comment: E está a atribuir o `DataSource` corretamente à `DataGridView`?